# All Stack Exchange emails come from Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, email, feedback

When I get an email about an inbox notification on any Stack Exchange site it comes from
"Stack Overflow <do-not-reply@stackoverflow.email>"

And I think they should at least change the name displayed on the front of the email if not the email address itself to stackexchange.email.

Also, I think they should remove the link at the top of all SE notifications which links to Stack Overflow and change it to link to Stack Exchange instead.